# Favorites doesn't display anything in Explorer sidebar

Tags: windows-7, windows-explorer, windows-registry, sidebar, favorites

On Windows 7 x64, I'm having an issue where the Favorites link in the sidebar fails to show any shortcuts, and the usually-cited fix of right-clicking on it and clicking either `Restore favorite links` or `Add current location to Favorites` has no effect.

[image]

I've made some changes to my registry, but they were both unrelated to Favorites and long before I noticed this issue.

Doing a registry search for Favorites returns the following relevant keys:

```
HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Applets\Regedit\Favorites
HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\MenuOrder\Favorites
HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\StartMenu\StartPanel\Favorites
HKLM\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\explorer\StartMenu\StartPanel\Favorites
```

Could someone on a system running 64-bit Windows 7 where this feature works be gracious enough to export their versions of these registry keys that I can take import into my registry?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a little more in-depth searching, I came across this batch script from Shawn Brink of [Seven Forums](https://www.sevenforums.com/tutorials/18583-user-folders-restore-default-location.html):

```
@echo off 

:: Created by: Shawn Brink
:: http://www.sevenforums.com
:: Tutorial: http://www.sevenforums.com/tutorials/18583-user-folders-restore-default-location.html

taskkill /f /im explorer.exe

timeout /t 2 /nobreak >nul

if not exist "%UserProfile%\Links" mkdir "%UserProfile%\Links"

reg add "HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\Shell Folders" /v "{BFB9D5E0-C6A9-404C-B2B2-AE6DB6AF4968}" /t REG_SZ /d "C:\Users\%USERNAME%\Links" /f

reg add "HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\User Shell Folders" /v "{BFB9D5E0-C6A9-404C-B2B2-AE6DB6AF4968}" /t REG_EXPAND_SZ /d %%USERPROFILE%%"\Links" /f

attrib +r -s -h "%USERPROFILE%\Links" /S /D

timeout /t 1 /nobreak >nul

start explorer.exe
```

Putting the above into a `.bat` file works to restore the `%USERPROFILE\Links` folder, which is apparently where Favorites pulls its entries from, although this is ridiculously confusing, as:

a) I don't remember ever having a Links folder in my user folder before, and...

b) There are now two folders cluttering up my User folder purely for the purpose of ensuring that the Favorites features works - both `%USERPROFILE%\Favorites` and `%USERPROFILE%\Links`

The motivation of Windows developers in tying up the functionality of Favorites with the completely redundant `%USERPROFILE%\Links` folder is beyond me.